# font awesome doesn't load net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

I'm trying to use [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io) for some icons, and am doing this by using the CDN.
I simply copied my font awesome embed code in the  of my page, as instructed.

```
   <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4c5806874b.js"></script>
```

But when I open the page, it tells my that webfontloader.js failed

Any ideas what goes wrong here?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Brighton Times</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 400px)"type="text/css" href="smallest-screens.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4c5806874b.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: @AlbertoRubio He's probably using [Fort Awesome](https://fortawesome.com/) - allows you to build a custom version of Font Awesome and other icon files.

Comment: @TiesonT. Oh, thanks. I didn't knew it. I'll delete my comment. Sry

Comment: Are you viewing the file via the file:/// protocol, or on a live server?

Comment: I view it locally (on my laptop), shouldn't that still work when I start my cdn code with 'https:// ' ? Also @TiesonT. , I'm using Font awesome, not Fort awesome

Comment: Fort Awesome IS Font Awesome. And no, not every script will work when the parent file is viewed locally.

Comment: Oh cool, so what is my code missing to make the browser understand that it's not a local javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, You're trying to use to load some fonts - try using the following link

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

if you want to see the output in HTML follow - i class and it should work.

Comment: My browser seems to think this css is faulty as it catches a syntaxerror on line 4. 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

Comment: Can you put this on JSFiddle or JSbin so can see the issue?

Comment: okay. What symbol are you trying to display? Do you have any js?

Comment: I'm trying to display the hamburger symbol (fa-bars), but even with commenting out that line and just trying to load the CDN I get errors. I know there are other options to get the hamburger icon, but I want to understand why I can't load this CDN. And yes I have some js, but the result is the same when I comment that js out.

Comment: check this out. Hope this helps. Is it what you need? https://jsbin.com/bexulunufe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes that works, thanks @Kaushal Patel! 
Do you have any idea why this bootstrapcdn works, and the font awesome cdn doesn't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112458/discussion-between-kaushal-patel-and-sjbuysse).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, You have given a wrong path. ex:font-face url etc. 
keep in mind,

```
<img src="Lanka.jpg">       <!-- Lanka.jpg is in the current folder -->
<img src="Asia/Lanka.jpg">  <!-- Lanka.jpg is in the Asia folder -->
<img src="/Asia/Lanka.jpg"> <!-- Asia folder is in root folder -->
<img src="../Lanka.jpg">    <!-- Lanka.jpg is in one folder up from current folder-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webfonts are not being found.Use a CDN or locally You could try downloading Webfonts with fa-solid-900.woff2,fa-brands-400.woff2,WebFont Regular.woff,WebFont Regular.woff2 depending on what is needed.Put the webfonts directory on the root folder.